# Wordpress: Adding a variable inside wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav

I am trying to add a variable inside wp_nav_menu, I am not sure how to do it, please help me! Here is a snippet of the code:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
                'menu' => 'Main Menu',
                'theme_location' => 'Main Menu',
                'container' => null,
                'container_class' => '',
                'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
                'menu_class' => '',
                'before' => '<span class="text1">',
                'after' => '</span><span class="text2"><a href="">' . the_title($post->ID) . '</a></span>',
            ));
```

PLEASE HELP ME!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output). It's quite likely to answer your question and more

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?  You may have to explain a little further, but this is how you'd add some additional values to `wp_nav_menu`.

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
            'MyItem' => 'My Value',                 // <--new item
            'MyotherItem' => 'My Other Value',      // <--other new item
            'menu' => 'Main Menu',
            'theme_location' => 'Main Menu',
            'container' => null,
            'container_class' => '',
            'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
            'menu_class' => '',
            'before' => '<span class="text1">',
            'after' => '</span><span class="text2"><a href="">' . the_title($post->ID) . '</a></span>',
));
```

Comment: so basically I need my html to come out like this 

`<li>
<span class="text1"><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></span>
<span class="text2">
<a href="/about">OUI</a>
</span>
</li>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will add URL

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu','menu_class' => 'drop', 'container' => 'nav', 'link_before' => '<span></span>') );
```

If you want it this way url

```
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu','menu_class' => 'drop', 'container' => 'nav', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>') );
```