# Insert PHP variables into WordPress register_sidebar widgets?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to add a widget area in my sidebar, that resizes the widgets depending on how many widgets are active. So like, if there are 3 active widgets, then each one will be like 33% the width of the container.

My widget is set up like :

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __( 'Front page Widgets' ),
    'id' => 'front-page',
    'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will appear on the front page.' ),
    'before_widget' =>'<li class="span4">',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
));
```

I can count the number of active widgets with this

```
$sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$footerWidgetCount =  count( $sidebars['footer-widgets'] );
```

But how would I go about passing $footerWidgetCount into my widget? Id like to be able to pass a new value for `before_widget` so I could resize it on the fly. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403837/wordpress-adding-a-variable-inside-wp-nav-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly:

```
$data = array(
  'name' => __( 'Front page Widgets' ),
  'id' => 'front-page',
  'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will appear on the front page.' ),
  'before_widget' =>'<li class="span4">',
  'before_title' => '<h3>',
  'after_title' => '</h3>'
);
$data['before_widget'] = "<li class='span$footerWidgetCount'>";
register_sidebar($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy, I will try to clean this up later, but how we are doing it in [HoverCraft](https://github.com/littlebizzy/hovercraft/blob/master/inc/sidebar-callout.php):

```
function hovercraft_callout() {
    
$callout_menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'cta-sidebar-callout', 
    'menu_class' => 'cta', 
    'container_class' => 'cta-sidebar-callout',
     'echo' => false,
    ) );
    
$after_widget_callout = ' '. $callout_menu . '</div>';
    
    $callout_array = array(
        'name'          => 'Callout',
        'id'            => 'hovercraft_callout',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-callout widget-wrapper">',
        'after_widget'  => $after_widget_callout,
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        );

register_sidebar($callout_array);
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'hovercraft_callout' );
```