# Insert html or custom function into WordPress dynamic_sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have registered a dynamic sidebar as follows
    register_sidebar(array(
            'id'            => 'widget-my-header',
            'name'          => 'My: Header',
            'before_widget' => '',
            'after_widget'  => '',
            'before_title'  => '',
            'after_title'   => '',
    ));

I call the dynamic sidebar in my template.

```
dynamic_sidebar('widget-my-header');
```

Is it even possible to inject a custom function into that dynamic_sidebar('widget-my-header'); ?

Say I have a function add_my_cool_headline()
And I want that to be the content for this dynamic_sidebar('widget-my-header');
Can htis be done?

I'm using a child theme, so I'm looking to having to replace the dynamic_sidebar('widget-my-header'); with a custom action

I know how to insert my own action hook into every template page, however I'd really like to avoid that. As there are many many theme files where it needs to be changed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860617/pass-value-into-widgets-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a class and register your widget in your sidebar

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'widget-my-header','before_widget' => '<div class="widget">','after_widget' => '</div>','before_title' => '<span>','after_title' => '</span>'));
}
class MYHeaderWidget extends WP_Widget {
    function MYHeaderWidget() {
    //Constructor
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'MYHeaderWidget Widget', 'description' => 'MYHeaderWidget' );
        $this->WP_Widget('MYHeaderWidget', 'widget-my-header', $widget_ops);
    }
    function widget($args, $instance) {
    // prints the widget
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);   ?>
<div class="">Hello</div>

    <?php
    }


}
register_widget('MYHeaderWidget');
```

Comment: I haven't been here that long- so it won't let vote up the answer. Sorry. But I did mark this as the correct answer! THANK YOU AGAIN!