# register_sidebar wordpress function before_widget

Tags: wordpress-theming

The register sidebar wordpress function has one parameter called "before_widget - HTML to place before every widget(default:`'<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'`) "
At the end it adds 
"Note: uses sprintf for variable substitution"(wp codex).
I test it on a site, and depending on the widget that I supply/activate it takes the name of the widget, an id plus a class e.g. for a search box it will became id="search-2" class="widget widget_search"
Where is this sprintf and where are these variables? Where is this function that manipulates this parameter? I checked the register_sidebar() function in wp-includes/widgets.php file but I could not find it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860617/pass-value-into-widgets-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sprintf and the variables you are searching for is present in wp-includes/widgets.php itself. Please refer the function [dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) present in wp-includes/widgets.php.

The exact line of code you are looking for is given below:

```
$params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_);
```