# Create a Dynamic Site Address in a Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm doing some work on an existing site that is based on the Wordpress theme, but uses about 15 plugins (Including Buddypress). One in particular is the WP Sliding Login|Dashboard plugin, which has a link to the user's activity feed. I found the code that creates that link in the wp-sliding-login-dashboard.php file:

```
  <?php
                if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                global $current_user;
                $username = $current_user->user_login;
                echo ' <li><a href="http://www.mywebsitename.com/members/' . $username . '/activity/">Activity Feed</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
```

I want to use this code to send the user to the same location, but using the a link at the top of the home page. Unfortunately, the home page links are all created using Wordpress menus, which as far as I can tell, only allow for the use of static links attached to existing pages.

Do I create a dummy page to link to that exits only to execute the above code? Is that even possible? Picture a five-year-old trying to read Shakespeare, and you have an idea of my ability as a coder, so feel free to engage me as such - i.e. if you say, "oh just create a scoping function instead of creating a global function", i would stare at you drooling and confused.

Images for clarity: The sliding login menu (WP-Sliding Login|Dashboard Plugin), showing the target URL in the status bar as www.ferrignofit.com/members/FerrignoFit/activity/ (the current logged in user is FerrignoFit):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbFNC.jpg

The main page Wordpress-based menu, which i want to go to the above URL, but is currently going to www.ferrignofit.com/activity/, a different page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZA0o.jpg

Comment: Definitively doable and I would be keen on writing an answer but there's some variables in your question that I need to know before I can answer. First of all a picture representation of what you want to do would be awesome as I don't know where the link should go. Next thing I can recommend is that you check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu so you can see that you can add stuff before or after the menu, even after menu items, etc. If I'm understanding correctly you want to add a static link with dynamic information so it works for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Here's an image from the sliding login, sending you to the correct page:

Comment: I don't see the picture, where did I miss it? or did you?

Comment: Bah! Tried to edit the original post to add images, but I need reputation of at least 10 to post an image.

Comment: Upload the image to an image repository and share the link.

Comment: Ah, that'll work! Added 2 links, couldn't add a 3rd because of rep, but it was just of the Wordpress Menu settings screen, showing the "Activity Feed" link on the home page linking to a page named "Activity".

Comment: is jQuery an option here? because it would be simpler that way. There's a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403837/wordpress-adding-a-variable-inside-wp-nav-menu but it's not properly answered because you are not adding a variable there as the question suggests, and in your particular case you want to add the variable that gets the username. On my end I would only know how to solve it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a jQuery solution for this specific issue. From seeing the images you have, what you want to do is target a specific anchor in your dynamic WordPress menu.

As you may be aware, you can create custom links for the WordPress menu function... it simply lets you set a label and a URL. You should create such item and just give it a hash for the URL for now.

Now set a class for that specific menu item so you can have a nice handle for jQuery to target it (otherwise you can use the dynamic class that WordPress creates for each specific menu-item).

One you have a class set or you know what you need to target then you can add this block of code before your menu.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {    
      var targetNav = $('li.customClassName a');
      var userName = '<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->display_name;?>';
      var userUrl = 'http://www.mywebsitename.com/members/'+ userName +'/activity/';
      targetNav.attr('href',userUrl);
    });
  </script>
<?php } else { ?>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {    
      var targetNav = $('li.customClassName a');
      targetNav.attr('href','http://www.stackoverflow.com');
    });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Please not that I am using PHP to get the current username in WordPress, after I get the username and I store it in the `userName` variable I use it in the `userUrl` to set it with the path that I want.

On another note, I'm using `is_user_logged_in()` so you have the option of making the link something else if the user is in fact not logged in. So with this `if` statement one of the two blocks of code will be output by PHP.

As soon as my two variables are set, I simply target my menu item with jQuery and modify the `href` attribute to replace the hash with the path and dynamic username.

Though this is not very good practice to mix JS and PHP, I'd like to learn myself here what other solutions someone can suggest so I'm posting this as a solution for your very specific issue.

I tested this code with my own WordPress site and it works, just remember that this code NEEDS to be in a PHP file otherwise the PHP used in the `<script>` tags won't mean anything to the server if it's in a `.js` file.

Comment: First: thank you tons for the response sulfureous! Second: Which php file am I adding the code to - header.php? When you say "target the menu item with jQuery, do you mean changing the targetNav value in the code above into the class name I gave the menu item (activity-feed)? And when you say "modify the href attribute", you just mean change the site address folliwing href in the code above to that same page (http://www.ferrignofit.com/activity-stream)?

Comment: Hi @AndrewFleischer : Yes go ahead and add the file to the header close to your call for the menu so it's easier to see what it's for. Yes on the target the menu item, change the `targetNav` to match your selector, and yes to modify the href attribute. If you want to send me a fiddle and a link to your site I'll help you adapt the code more to your exact requirements. The main thing to modify will be the variables for this to work well for you.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that should work according to what you mentioned in your questions above. Please let me know if this works for you and I'll add it to the body of the post. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/tfTTS/

Comment: Thanks sulfureous - used the update code from the fiddle, but the activity feed isn't going anywhere, thought i'm sure it's something i'm not implementing correctly. I've still got the Activity Feed menu item with just a "#" as the url, and i've set the class to activity-feed. Do I want to change the url to www.ferrignofit.com/activity-feed/    ?

Comment: At this stage I would need to see all the code in place to debug what would possibly be going on, do you have a test environment we can check to make sure jQuery is in the right place, make sure the code is adapted well to your needs.

Comment: I'm looking at the live site right now and browsing the source code and I see that on that particular menu item (while logged out of course because I don't have an account there) has a class of: `.ActivityFeed` ... in my fiddle the class is spelled differently as I understood from your previous comments. Try checking that all your selectors match perfectly, remember CSS an JS are case sensitive when it comes to selectors and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I should have had a test environment set up already, i'll create one for you to take a look at & message you when I do. I also realize you're going above and beyond the call of duty on this one, and I really appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn, hit me up when the environment is setup and we'll put a good resolution to this question.